# Adding Select All to a DataGridView Column Header in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have created a DataGridView in Windows Form. Each row will have a Checkbox. I would like to have the Select ll option, so that when the user click on the Column Header, it selects or deselects( toggles) all the checkbox in the DataGridview.

Any idea how I can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
private bool toggle = false;

myGrid.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(myClass_ColumnHeaderMouseClick);

private void myClass_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
  foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in (DataGridView)sender.cells)
  {
    if(toggle)
      cell.Value = 1;
    else
      cell.Value = 0;
  }

  if(toggle)
    toggle = false;
  else
    toggle = true;
}
```

this should do the trick